# How to generate a border around a string in Bash shell script?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to generate a border around a given string in Bash using characters like `-` and `|` and automatically expand to the length of the string? The given string should not include EOF sequences and be removed when processed.

```
echo "------------------"
echo "| External Drive |"
echo "------------------"
```

Comment: What is your attempt so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70615/bash-script-echo-output-in-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little function that does it, without external tools:

```
border () {
    local str="$*"      # Put all arguments into single string
    local len=${#str}
    local i
    for ((i = 0; i < len + 4; ++i)); do
        printf '-'
    done
    printf '\n| %s |\n' "$str"
    for ((i = 0; i < len + 4; ++i)); do
        printf '-'
    done
    echo
}
```

Once this is sourced by, for example, adding it to your `.bashrc`, it can be called without quoting:

```
$ border multiple words
------------------
| multiple words |
------------------
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70615/bash-script-echo-output-in-box#250094) on another Stack Exchange site which works using sed. It had different wording for the question.

```
border()
{
    title="| $1 |"
    edge=$(echo "$title" | sed 's/./-/g')
    echo "$edge"
    echo "$title"
    echo "$edge"
}

border "External Drive"
```

*results*

```
------------------
| External Drive |
------------------
```