# Add hash or any character before/after sentence?

Tags: bash, printing, echo

I need to add / print a specific number of characters after and before a sentence with a line ..

Example:

I am having below:

```
SCRIPT OUTPUT
```

I need to display it as:

```
#############
SCRIPT OUTPUT
#############
```

And if it was:

```
SCRIPT OUTPUT FROM INPUTS
```

I would need this as:

```
#########################
SCRIPT OUTPUT FROM INPUTS
#########################
```

So, it depends on the length of the sentence.
For sure, a one line command would be better.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. This is not a free Code-for-me website.

Comment: Have a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70615/bash-script-echo-output-in-box

Comment: _Very_ similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996057/how-to-generate-a-border-around-a-string-in-bash-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed and got what I needed:
Thanks for your help ...

```
delim='#'
header='string'
echo $header|sed 's/./'$delim'/g'
echo $header
echo $header|sed 's/./'$delim'/g'
```